# REST, and IE Explorer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I using a simple jQuery add and remove hide class to display an animated awesome font to indicating file request is loading - page opens with the div containing the animated awesome font with hide remove while the div that displays the JSOM query output is hidden and once the JSOM is completed jquery hides the div with the spinning loader and unhides the div to reveal the JSOM result. Works great used it all the time.

Moving to REST. First I have noticed that REST is a bit slower but the real issue I'm having is that with IE once the REST starts running the animated load spinner stops - works fine in Chrome - giving the impression that there is an error. Once the REST has completed, the jQuery does the hide switch. But with IE the REST take much longer to complete then in Chrome.

Any ideas why the animated awesome font stop and wht is take longer to rub in IE?

Comment: Any javascript errors in the browser's console? It's **very** hard to judge if the code is IE-compatible without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing is clear it is a browser related issue and nothing related to Javascript or REST api's or SharePoint. We can say here that all new features and controls are not fully supported/compatible in IE and there are issues which Microsoft has acknowledged while working with SharePoint on IE browser. You may try IE edge if you haven't tried yet and see if the issue still persists. Also you can check if IE is running in compatible mode.

From my experience, At the end the answer will be that this is expected in IE.